# Load a view when a button is clicked mac osx application

Tags: macos, cocoa

How to load a new view when user touches a button (something like pushing a view for iOs) (this is for a mac application)? In .Net we can use show, likewise is there any method to load a view?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load a view from xib the easiest way is to use `NSViewController`.

```
- (IBAction)showMyAmazingView:(id)sender
{
    NSViewController* myViewController = [[NSViewController] alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyAmazingView" bundle:nil];

    NSView* myAmazingView = myViewController.view;

    // Do whatever you want with myAmazingView
}
```

If you want to create your (custom)view programmatically you should initialize it first:

```
- (IBAction)showMyAmazingView:(id)sender
{
    MyAmazingViewSubclass* myAmazingView = [[MyAmazingViewSubclass] alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100)];

    // Do whatever you want with myAmazingView
}
```

After your view is loaded you need to place it to another view (superview) to display it. For example for your window's client view:

```
[window.clientView addSubview:myAmazingView];
```

And also you can position your view with `-setFrame:` method.